# How can I manage duplicate letters in Wordle Game (JavaFx)?

Tags: java, algorithm

In my algorithm to compare the secret word with the guessed word, I need to manage the duplicated letters. For example,

 if the secret word is `newly` and the guessed word is `newer`, the output of this should be "GGGWW" (G = green(Correct Place), W = White(The Letter isn't in the secret word)), 
 but instead my algorithm down below outputs "GGGYW" (Y = Yellow(Letter is in the word but not the right place)).

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (secret.charAt(i) == prop.charAt(i)) {
                status[i] = LetterStatus.IN;
            } else if (secret.contains(Character.toString(prop.charAt(i)))) {
                status[i] = LetterStatus.OK;
            } else {
                status[i] = LetterStatus.NOTIN;
            }
        }
        return status;
```

secret = secretword, the array status is an enum of `(IN, OK, NOTIN)`, so the letter and prop status is the guessed word.

Any ideas on how to modify this code to solve my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to take the number of occurrences into account. So, process the exact matches first, recording the letters not found so far. For each other occurrence in the guess, remove the letter from the recorded letters, so that you will not match it again. E.g.

```java
ArrayList<Character> missing = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if(secret.charAt(i) == prop.charAt(i)) {
        status[i] = LetterStatus.IN;
    }
    else missing.add(secret.charAt(i));
}
if(!missing.isEmpty()) {
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      if(secret.charAt(i) != prop.charAt(i)) {
        Object ch = prop.charAt(i); // ensure to use remove(Object) not remove(int)
        status[i] = missing.remove(ch)? LetterStatus.OK: LetterStatus.NOTIN;
      }
  }
}
```

For large data, you’d use something like a `Map<Character,Integer>` to record the number of occurrences for each element, but since we have at most five elements here, using an `ArrayList` is simpler while providing reasonable performance. It’s just important to keep in mind that this approach would not scale to other problems.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest seems to be just to override matched letter in a secret every time `secret` character matches `prop` character and then check for the letters whether they're in or not in the word

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     if (secret.charAt(i) == prop.charAt(i)) {
         status[i] = LetterStatus.IN;
         secret = secret.substring(0, i) + "-" + secret.substring(i+1); // or any other invalid character that will not be provided by user
     }
 }

 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     if(status[i] == null) {
        if (secret.contains(Character.toString(prop.charAt(i)))) {
            status[i] = LetterStatus.OK;
        } else {
            status[i] = LetterStatus.NOTIN;
        }
     }
  }

  return status;
```

There is additional question how would you like to treat repeating characters that are yellow (let's say the user provided `newee` - should both `e` be yellow or only one) and maybe you'd need to tune up a little bit this code